# Get Joomla SEF Url from Database Query

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef

i need an export of all Joomla Articles in a specific category, but with the URL they are on. (So introtext, fulltext, url)

Has anybody a quick way how I can get the Joomla SEF Url if i only have the article ID?

Comment: SEF URLs of the articles aren't stored in Joomla database

Answer (score 1):

You can use jroute and the contenthelperroute to get the sef urls.

```
JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($id, $catid, $language));
```

If you only have the article ID's you can try this without $catid and $language. They are optional.